# Get-MaskingSet in PowerShell 2.0

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, storage

I'm trying to retrieve the current masking sets using *PowerShell 2.0* on a *Windows Server 2008 R2*. Unfortunately, the cmdlet `Get-MaskingSet` does not exist under this `PowerShell` version.
Are there any other ways to retrieve this list from this particular configuration?

> Get-MaskingSet
>   Applies To: Windows 8.1, Windows PowerShell 4.0, Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: This might seem like an obvious point, but why not install powershell 4.0 on the server?

Comment: @Colyn1337 I would like to, but it needs to be performed with the default installation.

Comment: You *could* create a new 08r2 base image and slip the WMF4.0 install in there.  I'm weighing the effort involved between reverse engineering a cmdlet or creating a new server WIM.  To me, creating a new server image would be the easiest and fastest.

Comment: @Colyn1337 That would be a great idea if I didn't have to deploy the packaged script over multiple servers which I'm not in charge of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use good old WMI:

```powershell
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\providers_v2" -Class "MSFT_StorageSubSystemToMaskingSet"
```

Not sure what bit of information you are after but this should get you started.

Comment: This namespace (`root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\providers_v2`) is not available for Windows 2008 R2 with SCVMM 2012.